# unable to set 'max.poll.records' under kafka consumer, where cons.poll still returns all records under partition

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have created **multi thread consumer** app to work upon various partitions.
Looking into various blogs i came to know about 'max.poll.records' property, in order to get control over the set of records from given topic, partition.(so it can quickly come out of Records loop and hence call cons.poll() to keep alive)

Problem is my processing logic takes time to process each record.
upon starting Cons-2 both start to work on same partition as Cons-1 still did not went for re-balance (i.e. cons.poll() not happened yet).

Increasing consumers so they can **re-balance** them selves, cons.poll() will not occur unless all records are processed.

I may not go for 'session.timeout.ms' as starting new consumer may also start working on same partition as of Cons-1.

I have tried setting property using :

```
props.put("max.poll.records",1);
props.put("max.poll.records","1");
```

but neither changed the no. of records from poll.

I am using Apache Kafka 9 and Below API.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0.1_1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`max.poll.records` property released in Kafka-0.10.0. It's not available in Kafka 0.9.0.1 version. See KAFKA-3007 task in the [release](https://archive.apache.org/dist/kafka/0.10.0.0/RELEASE_NOTES.html) notes.

If your processing of records took much time, the below link might be helpful.

[AdvancedConsumer.java](https://github.com/omkreddy/kafka-examples/blob/master/consumer/src/main/java/kafka/examples/consumer/advanced/AdvancedConsumer.java)

Comment: here the problem is you are having single thread consumer thread that will process each record. where as i am consuming multiple records.

Comment: I didn't get your point. Basically, you have to start multiple consumers which belongs to the same group. There-by records from multiple partitions gets processed simultaneously.

Comment: exactly, its actually multi-consumer program. I also need to consume records multi threaded. to not waste time in processing single records. and hence commit offset based on the records being processed then. Still your code has quite new things that are helpful and learned it.